# Is std::type_index safe across DLLs

Tags: c++, c++11, dll

Let's say that I have a main DLL where there's a class like this:

```
class Test
{
public:

    typedef std::unordered_map< std::type_index, int > Map;

    template < typename T > void SetValue(int val)
    {
        SetValue(std::type_index(typeid(T)), val);
    }

    template < typename T > int GetValue()
    {
        return GetValue(std::type_index(typeid(T)));
    }

protected:

    // Defined in .cpp file
    void SetValue(const std::type_index & idx, int val)
    {
        m_Map[idx] = val;
    }

    // Defined in .cpp file
    int GetValue(const std::type_index & idx)
    {
        Map::const_iterator itr = m_Map.find(idx);

        if (itr != m_Map.cend())
        {
            return itr->second;
        }

        return 0;
    }

private:

    Map m_Map;
};
```

And I share an instance of that class through several DLLs. And in one of the DLLs I set some values like this:

```
template < typename T > struct Dummy
{

};

void InitFunc(Test * t)
{
    t->SetValue< Dummy<int> >(32);
    t->SetValue< Dummy<char> >(10);
    t->SetValue< Dummy<float> >(27);
}
```

And in another DLL I attempt to get those values using the same `Dummy` type. Would I get those same values or 0?

Comment: You should be more concerned whether you get a crash when trying to use one of your `Test` ojbects created in one DLL, and passed to another DLL.  All your DLL's have to be compiled with the same compiler, same options, make sure the heap used is the same (for the `unordered_map`), etc.

Comment: The use of `std::unordered_map` was just an example. It seems I formed the question a bit wrong. My question was if `std::type_index` would point to the same index. The `hash_code` value would be the same.

Comment: My point is that you can't even consider anything unless the DLL's are built exactly the same.  Also, it doesn't have to be an `unordered_map` -- if your `Test` class eventually does *any* memory management, explicit or implicit, usage of `Test` between DLL's is problematic if the same heap is not used.

Comment: I see. I'm guessing this answers my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This hugely depends on your definition of 'safe' and your deployment environment.

The crux of the argument of @SergeyA's answer is that the compiler generates `std::type_info` objects in each compilation unit - which are then coalesced by the linker when each DLL is linked.

Whilst a `std::type_info` will have an interface defined by the standard, the implementation (and particularly, storage layout) is an implementation detail that may change between compilers, compiler versions, and compiler options.

Furthermore from [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index)

> The type_index class is a wrapper class around a std::type_info object, that can be used as index in associative and unordered associative containers. The relationship with type_info object is maintained through a pointer'

So now, we're relying on a several definitions of *pointers* into each DLL as well.

Thinking of some of the things you might do with a `std::type_index` - there's a high likelihood the results will be context dependent - largely dependant on where they are called from.

Now onto the question: Is this safe? Likely not.  As a general rule, you should avoid exposing almost all of the std library (and particularly STL containers) across DLL interface boundaries.

If you do insist on doing so, it's only ever got a change of work in these very limited circumstances:

- All components are built with precisely the same compiler
- All components are built with precisely the same compiler options (debug vs release has always been a massive issue on Windows)
- All components are deployed together as one unit
- None of the components exposes an API to anybody else

This is actually true of a great deal of commercial software, and you'll find it is done more often than you think, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you are violating ODR - One Definition Rule. Seems like your 'Dummy' type is independently defined in two different units of translations, and that's a no-no-no :). Now, this brings you into undefined land, and here anything is possible - you can get same values, different values or no values at all.

Comment: This answer is absolutely wrong. ODR does *not* apply to class templates, which Dummy is. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition `There can be more than one definition in a program, as long as each definition appears in a different translation unit, of each of the following: class type, enumeration type, inline function with external linkage inline variable with external linkage (since C++17), class template, non-static function template, static data member of a class template, member function of a class template, partial template specialization, [...]`

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier You skipped an important part: `..., as long as all of the following is true: ... each definition consists of the same sequence of tokens (typically, appears in the same header file)`